# Multivalued solution of PDE ${v_{xx}v_{yy}-v_{xy}^{2}}={(1+v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2})^2}$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, jets, dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, mp.mathematical-physics

Let's start with a definition:

Definition: A scalar k-th order differential equation on a smooth manifold $M$,
is $F(x,v,\frac{\partial {^\left | \sigma  \right |}v}{\partial x^\sigma })=0 $
for $\left | \sigma  \right |\leqslant k   $.

This equation can be viewed as hypersurface $E=F(x,u,p_\sigma )=0\subset J^kM$ in the space of k-jets.

An n-dimensional integral manifold $L$ of the Cartan distribution is called a **multivalued solution** of equation E, if $L\subset E$.

(see A.G. Kushner's paper about the classification of Monge-Ampère equations)

> How can we find the multivalued solution of the equation
>   $\frac{v_{xx}v_{yy}-v_{xy}^{2}}{(1+v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2})^2}=1 $?

Comment: What do you mean by "compute"? Are you looking for only solutions that have an explicit formula?

Comment: I am just looking for multivalued solution  of this equation, for more information see http://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/~mikarm/TALLER_7/pdf/kushner.pdf

Comment: I think that in Kushner's notes, that you gave a link to, there is a proof that the Monge-Ampere equation you are interested in is contact equivalent to the Laplace equation. If I have that correct, you might try to find a contact transformation (also called a hodograph transformation) to turn your equation into the Laplace equation, and then use the standard Newton potential for the Laplace equation to generate a large family of global solutions.

Comment: Actually, the final equation asserts that the (multivalued) graph $z = v(x,y)$ has Gauss curvature equal to $1$.  Hence, as Lie knew, it is *not* contact-equivalent to Laplace's equation (though it is, of course, elliptic); it is not even Darboux-integrable (again, Lie). Rather, it is contact equivalent to the elliptic sinh-Gordon equation $\Delta u = \mathrm{sinh}\ u$, which is an integrable equation.  Of course, there are many multi-valued solutions, such as $v(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, and many can be found using integrable systems techniques.

Comment: (correction)  What I wrote above about the given equation being contact equivalent to the elliptic sinh-Gordon equation is not correct.  Instead, they are Bäcklund equivalent.  I forgot that one has to make an integrable extension of the above equation before there is a prolongation equivalence with the elliptic sinh-Gordon equation.  The reason is that the above equation does not have any (complex) Riemann invariants until one uses an integrable extension to kill two conservation laws to generate them, and these then become the independent variables in the sinh-Gordon equation.

Comment: Do you want to find one multivalued solution, or all possible multivalued solutions?

Comment: As you see in definition and examples of lecture note of A.G.Kushner, we construct multivalued solution by parameter $t$, so I am looking for all possible multivalued solutions in your sense. 

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kushner's notes, but whatever he does, it's not going to give you *all* of the multi-valued solutions explicitly in terms of two arbitrary functions of one variable (or one holomorphic function of one variable), since the equation is not Darboux-integrable.